# WSO2 ESB & DSS response caching

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am developing an ESB & DSS services and I would like to set the "response caching parameter" to true when deploy. How can I enable this in the proxy and dss xml descriptor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add response caching to ESB proxy service please read [this](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Response+Caching) 
tutorial. To enable that for a Data service in DSS please read [this](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS301/Response+Caching) tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is what I try to avoid. I have to deploy 70 services, and enable this setting for each service manually is not an option.

Comment: If so then you have to enable Global level engagement. Please note that it will apply caching for all the messages coming into that particular server instance. All the responses from all the services will be cached. Please refer [1] and enable wso2caching. Same procedure is applicable to ESB and DSS.

Comment: I dont have to cache all services deployed, just these 70 services. The rest should not cache the response.